# Extract lists by specific keywords from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I would need to extract from a list of list only the lists that contain special keywords:

```
my_list= [['sussidi', '14,5'],
 ['sussidi', '42,5', 'miliardi'],
 ['esclusioni.', "l'anno", 'scorso,', '41'],
 ['esclusioni.', "l'anno", 'scorso,', '22', 'milioni'],
 ['scorso,', '41', 'milioni', 'visitatori'],
 ['40', 'milioni', 'visitatori'],
 ['paese', 'aspettava', '40'],
 ['aspettava', '40', 'milioni']]
```

I would like to extract only those lists that contains the following keywords:

```
keywords = ['visitatori','sussidi']
```

I did:

```
for item in my_list:
    print([x for x in item if any(kw in x for kw in keywords)])
```

but it gives me only the keywords:

```
['sussidi']
['sussidi']
[]
[]
['visitatori']
['visitatori']
[]
[]
```

My expected output would be

```
['sussidi', '14,5']
['sussidi', '42,5', 'miliardi']
[]
[]
['scorso,', '41', 'milioni', 'visitatori']
['40', 'milioni', 'visitatori']
[]
[]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Removed `pandas` tag as it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I am working with a dataframe but in this case, for this specific problem, there was no mention on the dataframe so thank you for having removed the tag

Comment: If you are working with pandas it's good to provide the dataframe you might get more better/ efficient solution. You can [edit] the question and update with changes. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR :)  I think it is perfectly fine in this case

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I really appreciated. All of them are extremely useful and valid but I had to mark only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
l=[y  if x  else [] for x , y in zip( pd.DataFrame(my_list).isin(keywords).any(1),my_list)]
[['sussidi', '14,5'], ['sussidi', '42,5', 'miliardi'], [], [], ['scorso,', '41', 'milioni', 'visitatori'], ['40', 'milioni', 'visitatori'], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many levels of loop (`x for x in item...`).  Just do:

```
for item in my_list:
     print(item if any(kw in item for kw in keywords) else [])
```

Comment: Sam approves of Samwise's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as a 1-line list comprehension:

`print([item for item in my_list if any([kw in item for kw in keywords])])`

This prints a list made from items (sub-lists) in `my_list` if any of the keywords are in that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=[lists if len(set(lists) & set(keywords))>0 else [] for lists in my_list ]
```

Using if-else in list comprehension search out for intersection between keywords & inner lists. If any element found, take the inner list else return []

Answer (score 0):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
ll = [l for s in kw for l in my_list if s in l]
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

That list comprehension is the equivalent of this nested for-loop:

```
for l in my_list:
    for s in kw:
        if s in l:
            print(l)
```

Output:

```
['sussidi', '14,5']
['sussidi', '42,5', 'miliardi']
['scorso,', '41', 'milioni', 'visitatori']
['40', 'milioni', 'visitatori']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually:

```py
    # Create a set of the keywords to check if a given
    # word in one of the inners list is a keyword 
    keywords_set = set(keywords)

    # create list in which you are going to store the
    # inner lists that satisfy your condition
    final_result = []
    
    for inner_list in my_list:
        for word in inner_list:
            if word in keywords_set:
                final_result.append(inner_list)
    
    print(final_result)
```

**Console Output:**

```py
    [
        ['sussidi', '14,5'], 
        ['sussidi', '42,5', 'miliardi'], 
        ['scorso,', '41', 'milioni', 'visitatori'], 
        ['40', 'milioni', 'visitatori']
    ]
```

The two level for loop can be written using functional programming instead of list comprehension, making use of the filter function and lambda functions:

```py
    final_result = filter(lambda inner_list: any(map(lambda word: word in keywords_set, inner_list)), my_list)
```

The most efficient way though, is using intersection (& symbol) operation of sets structures:

```py
    final_result = filter(lambda inner_list: len(keywords_set & set(inner_list)) > 0, my_list)
```

The important part is this: `len(keywords_set & set(inner_list)) > 0`
We are checking that the intersection of these 2 sets is the empty set.